# angular-ui-bootstrap accordion not working on yeoman-generator

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am working on the implementation of accordion using angular-ui-bootstrap on the top of yeoman [swiip-generator](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular). 
Using the example from the official angular-ui-bootstrap page to display simple accordion but it is not working, with the error in console state that

```
angular.js:13920 Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'uibAccordion', required by directive 'uibAccordionGroup', can't be found!
```

Anybody had the similar problem and know the solution?

the html used:

```
<div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default">
  <uib-accordion-heading>
    I can have markup, too!
  </uib-accordion-heading>
   This is just some content to illustrate fancy headings.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

have you inject the module in your `angular.module` ?
which verison are you using?

Comment: yes, in the index.module page I included module `ui.bootstrap`.
I use the one that the swiip use (v 1.3) then tried to update it to the current one (v 2.1.4). Both return the same error

Comment: this is me being stupid. there is an error in registering the module due to my custom bower rule that I set before and it affected some library including angular-bootstrap